# NLP: Curating definitional summaries for a specific term from textbook

Tags: nlp, summarization

I would like to be able to curate definitional summaries for a specific term from a textbook.

For example, from a Biology textbook, I would like to be able form a concise summary for the word "mitochondria". I have tried this by first parsing through the textbook for all sentences that contain the word "mitochondria", and feeding those sentences through summarization algorithms such as TextRank and LexRank, but those algorithms were not able to determine "definitional" sentences that well.

By definitional summaries, I mean useful sentences as far as a definition goes. For example, the sentence "The mitochondria is the powerhouse of the cell" would be a definitional sentence while the sentence "Fungal cells also contain mitochondria and a complex system of internal membranes, including the endoplasmic reticulum and Golgi apparatus" is not really pertinent to the definition of the mitochondria.

Any help or leads would be very much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

This is a very open ended question. I can try to point how I would approach this...

One way would be to use some kind of vector representation for text ([word2vec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word2vec)
or sent2vec come to mind).

Then by encoding the average of the sentences in vector format and checking the cosine similarity of this and of the term you seek, you could be getting something close to the definitional sentences you seek.

Even testing the cosine similarity of the averaged sentences you get out of the summary algorithm and the term might get you close to judge how close you are

Answer (score 0):

There isn't really a straightforward way to do this, but you do have some options:

1. Just use a regex for "mitochondria is". It is the stupidest possible thing, but given a textbook it might prove satisfactory. It's simple enough testing should be easy, and at worst provides a baseline to compare alternatives to.
2. Run a parser (example: [Stanford Parser](https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/lex-parser.shtml)) on each sentence with the word "mitochondria", and extract sentences where mitochondria is the subject. This would eliminate the negative example you gave. You would have to tune this, perhaps restricting main verbs, accounting for coordinators, and so on.
3. Use **Information Extraction** (example: [Stanford OpenIE](https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/openie.html)) to get a list of facts about mitochondria (like `is-in(mitochondria, cell)`) and do something with that.